# scaling factor in gaussion elimination

Tags: algorithm

ALGORITHM ForwardElimination(A[1..n, 1..n], b[1..n])
//Applies Gaussian elimination to matrix A of a system’s coefficients,
//augmented with vector b of the system’s right-hand side values
//Input: Matrix A[1..n, 1..n] and column-vector b[1..n]
//Output: An equivalent upper-triangular matrix in place of A with the
//corresponding right-hand side values in the (n + 1)st column
for i ←1 to n do A[i, n + 1]←b[i] //augments the matrix
for i ←1 to n − 1 do
for j ←i + 1 to n do
for k←i to n + 1 do
A[j, k]←A[j, k]− A[i, k] ∗ A[j, i]/ A[i, i]

> There are two important observations to make about this pseudocode.
>   First, it is not always correct: if A[i, i]= 0, we cannot divide by it
>   and hence cannot use the ith row as a pivot for the ith iteration of
>   the algorithm. In such a case, we should take advantage of the first
>   elementary operation and exchange the ith row with some row below it
>   that has a nonzero coefficient in the ith column. (If the system has a
>   unique solution, which is the normal case for systems under
>   consideration, such a row must exist.) Since we have to be prepared
>   for the possibility of row exchanges anyway, we can take care of
>   another potential difficulty: the possibility that A[i, i] is so small
>   and consequently the scaling factor A[j, i]/A[i, i] so large that the
>   new value of A[j, k]might become distorted by a round-off error caused
>   by a subtraction of two numbers of greatly different magnitudes.3 To
>   avoid this problem, we can always look for a row with the largest
>   absolute value of the coefficient in the ith column, exchange it with
>   the ith row, and then use the new A[i, i] as the ith iteration’s
>   pivot. This modification, called partial pivoting, guarantees that the
>   magnitude of the scaling factor will never exceed 1.

My questions on above text are

1. What does author mean by " possibility that A[i, i] is so small and consequently the scaling factor A[j, i]/A[i, i] is so large" ? Request to explain here with simple example.
2. In extension to above questions what does author mean by "new value of A[j, k]might become distorted by a round-off error caused by a subtraction of two
   numbers of greatly different magnitudes" ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think theses comments are only useful when you want to program it. The mains issue there is the way to represent numbers.

Let's say that A[i,i] is *reaaally* small, and that A[j,i]/A[i,i] is around 10^12. In itself, this is not a problem, but when you want to manipulate this number, you won't manipulate exactly 10^12 but an approximation of this number. Most of the time, the norm used for large number representation is [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) (in case you want to go in depth).

The main thing to remember is that these are not exact number, which mean that 10^12 and 10^12 -1 have the same representation. (You can try it [there](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) if you want to)

so, if we have high values, we might not perform the right operation, because we won't actually work on the right number. I tried to make a little program to illustrate these differences you can get  :

```
int main()
{
   float bigOne = 100000000000000;
   float smallerOne = 99990000000000; 
   float expectedSubstraction = 10000000000;
   float divisionFactor = 1000000;
   cout << (bigOne-smallerOne)/divisionFactor << endl;
   cout<< "expected : " << expectedSubstraction/divisionFactor << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

[Try it there](http://ideone.com/XkybDa)

. Now that's not a big difference, but it could snowball out of control after a few more iterations ...

So, we can have a difference between the *calculated* **A[i, k] ∗ A[j, i]/ A[i, i]** and the *real* **A[i, k] ∗ A[j, i]/ A[i, i]**

Also, if **A[j, k]** is fairly small, and **A[i, k] ∗ A[j, i]/ A[i, i]** is still really big, we won't get the *exact* value, since we will perform an operation on an exact number and a representation of a big number. This won't necessarly be a big difference, but it can lead to absrud result if the error snowballs on multiple iterations.

Hope that helped !

Answer (score 0):

To see what the author means, consider the simplest example of Gaussian elimination, when we have only two linear equations:

```
ax+by=c
dx+ey=f
```

I replaced A[i,j] with letters a, b, d, e, and b[k] with letters c and f to make the formulas easier to read.

In order to eliminate y from the first equation, we rewrite the second equation as

```
y=(f-dx)/e            /* (1) */
```

perform a substitution to compute `x`

```
x=(ce-bf)/(ae-bd)   /* (2) */
```

and then go back to compute `y` from `x`.

Now consider what happens in (1) above when `e` in the original equation is very small, say, 10<sup>-320</sup>. The scaling factor (i.e. the number by which you multiply `f-dx` to obtain `y`) is `1/e`, or 10<sup>320</sup>. Multiplying by a number that large risks overflowing the exponent in the floating point representation of a number. That is what the author meant by the passage that you quote in the first part of your question.

For the part two of your question consider formula (2) above. When `ce` is very small in comparison to `bf` (or `bf` is very small in comparison to `ce`) the result of subtraction is dominated by the bigger number because of the way the floating point numbers are represented. Essentially, when one number is several orders of magnitude smaller than the other one, the result of addition or subtraction is identical to the bigger number. The author wanted to mention that this could easily happen in the process of computing a solution using Gaussian elimination.